# compare one column between all csv files in a folder in python and output results

Tags: python-2.7, loops, csv, pandas

I have 80 csv files in a folder, and want to compare the first column (no headers in my files) of every file with all other first column of the other files( no need to repeat for example fileA,FileB to FileB,FileA)
So this column may contain thousands of lines, with one username in each line. And the objective is to output in a new csv file something like this:

output.csv:

```
fileA,fileB,3,'James'-'samuel'-'Gregg'

fileA,filec,5,'Gregg'-'Traba'-'foo'
```

So I started trying to untangle it, but i got stuck in infinite for loops:

```
import csv as csv
output = open('output.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)
list_file = ['fileA.csv', 'fileB', 'fileC.csv', 'fileD.csv', 'fileE.csv']
for file1 in list_files:
    csv_obj = csv.reader(open(file1, 'rb'))
    for file2 in list_files:
        csv_obj2 = csv.reader(open(file2, 'rb'))
        for line in csv_obj:
            for line1 in csv_obj2:
                if line == line2 ....
```

At this point I can't figure out what can be used to avoid these endless for loops!? What should i use instead?

**update**

Sample CSV files:

file1.csv:

```
7627012826,jamesGam,followers,623,370,5,293,Tue
2955713991,samRichard,followers,3769,3383,45,170,Wed
250898317,CamalSarj,followers,1352,2365,111,10954,Sat
928898317,JangiBell,followers,9152,2365,731,74954,Sat
```

file2.csv:

```
118898359,JangiBell,followers,73152,9815,381,177954,Sat
9227010126,jorgebel,followers,7223,37550,5,9193,Sat
1105742991,samRichard,followers,7609,8283,985,285,Wed
623898922,Estovagre,followers,956,8393,921,1981,Tue
```

the output would be in the output.csv in this format:

```
file1,file2,2,'samRichard'-'JangiBell'
```

Comment: Can you explain the format of `output.csv`?

Comment: the format of the output.csv file would be entries, each line/entry is two filenames followed by total common usernames found, followed by all common usernames found in both files as such:fileA,fileb,2,'Jame'-'Sal'

Comment: @Joesal, this looks like an easy task for Pandas... Could you provide a small reproducible sample data sets (for example 2 CSV files, with 2-3 columns and 3 rows each) in CSV format and desired resulting CSV, so we could see exactly what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @MaxU i have updated the quetion

Comment: @Joesal, i don't understand an algorithm for selecting data for your desired `output.csv`. Why did you join __second__ row from  `file1` with the __first__ row from `file2` - what is the logic behind it?

Comment: @MaxU because those two exists in file1 and file2, regardless of the order of appearance. I'm comparing the two files, and output the filenames and the 'usernames' that exist in both

Comment: @Joesal, can all those 80 CSV be read in memory altogether? Will they fit into RAM?

Comment: @MaxU they wouldn't fit into the RAM, they would fit if only i read-in the second column of each file, which is the column that contains the usernames that i'm trying to compare and count, all other columns are not of importance to produce the output.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only used pandas for csv reading and writing. It seemed to me that the main part of the logic needed was set intersections (to get names in common) and the pairwise matching.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv'] # use os.listdir here if you want

usernames = {}
output = []

# load the username column that you're interested in
# into a dict
# keys are the filenames;
# values are the usernames, but as a set

for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None)
    usernames[f] = set(df[1].values) # second column, as in your sample csvs

# two loops for pairwise matching
for (i, file_i) in enumerate(sorted(usernames)):
    for (j, file_j) in enumerate(sorted(usernames)):
        # prevent recalculating a pair
        if j > i:

            # set intersection
            intersect = usernames[file_i] & usernames[file_j]

            # just getting the custom string format you wanted:
            # single-quoted names, joined by hyphens
            formatted_items = ["'{}'".format(item) for item in list(intersect)]
            formatted_string = '-'.join(formatted_items)

            # write new row of output
            newrow = [file_i[:-4],      # take out .csv extension from string
                      file_j[:-4],
                      len(intersect),   # score (names in common)
                      formatted_string]
            output.append(newrow)

# output csv
pd.DataFrame(output).to_csv('output.csv', index=None,
                            header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i have understand what do you want as output, however:

```
import csv
list_file = ['fileA.csv', 'fileB.csv', 'fileC.csv', 'fileD.csv', 'fileE.csv']
for i in range(len(list_file)):
    reader_i = csv.reader(open(list_file[i], 'rb'))
    #to eliminate repeted elements i start the second loop from i
    for j in range(i, len(list_file)):
        reader_i = csv.reader(open(list_file[j], 'rb')) 
        for line_i, line_j in zip(reader_i, reader_j):
            if line_i[0]==line_j[0]:
               ...
```

I hope i help you. Good work.